# Consider $S = \{(n,n)\mid n\in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Prove $S$ is a subring of $\Bbb Q \times \Bbb Q$ but not an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider $S = \{(n,n)\mid n\in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Prove $S$ is a subring of $R$ but not an ideal in $R$, where $R = \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$.

I don't know how to do this one... any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Darn it, yes.

Comment: You really should be able to check that it's a subring yourself. All you have to do is go through the ring axioms, and check that $S$ satisfies all of these, which should be routine. If you get stuck on any specific axiom, then say so.

Comment: @DerekHolt You're absolutely right. Going into this I didn't really understand what an ideal was. I understand it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

When we are talking about rings with a unit then:

$S$ is a subring of ring $R$ iff it contains the identity and $a,b\in S$
implies that $a+b,a-b$ and $ab$ belong to $S$.

An ideal $I$ that contains the identity of the ring coincides with the ring. This because: $1\in I\Rightarrow r=r1\in I$ for every $r\in R$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is any ring, then the diagonal $\{\,(a,a) \mid a\in A\,\}$ is always a subring of$~A\times A$, and always isomorphic to$~A$, namely it is the image of the ring morphism (which is trivial to check) $A\to A\times A:a\mapsto(a,a)$. Since it contains the unit of multiplication in $A\times A$ (namely $(1_A,1_A)$) it could only be an ideal if it were all of $A\times A$ (since every element is multiple of the multiplicative unit). But the latter only happens when $A$ is the trivial ring, not when $A=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @DanielRust: Right, corrected in the obvious manner.

Answer (score 1):

Let's study it from an abstract point of view. If $R$ is any ring (with unit or not), the set
$$
D=\{(r,r):r\in R\}
$$
is always a subring of the product ring $S=R\times R$ and the verification is an easy exercise.

If $D$ were an ideal of $S$, we'd have
$$
(r,r)(s,0)=(rs,0)\in D
$$
for all $r,s\in R$, which means $rs=0$, for all $r,s\in R$. That is, $R$ must have trivial multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $S \cong \mathbb{Q}$ by $(n,n) \mapsto n$. So I assume that the question is why $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$ but not an ideal.

Clearly, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a ring. Let us check it is closed to addition and multiplication: if $x,y \in \mathbb{Q}$ are rational number then $x \pm y$ and $xy$ are also rationals. Moreover, $0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $1 \in \mathbb{Q}$. Hence, it is a subring of \mathbb{R}$.

It is not an ideal of $\mathbb{R}$ since if it was and ideal $I := \mathbb{Q} \lhd \mathbb{R}$ then for any $i \in I$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$ we should have $ri \in I$. But take $i = 1 \in I$ and $r = \sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}$, then $ri = \sqrt{2}$ is not rational and hence $ri \notin I$. Thus, $I$ is not an ideal of $\mathbb{R}$.

Remark: note that a field $K$ has only trivial ideals: $\{ 0 \}$ and $K$ itself.

Edit: I wrote this answer before the question was edited and chaged.